Getting reason=2 when connecting to hostapd AP using wpa_supplicant via EAP-MD5
I am learning EAP-MD5 and trying to break it manually (like rfc says). But unable to get to the EAP negotiation. The supplicant is getting successfully associated with the AP but then its getting deauth just after open authentication with reason code 2. Logs from wpa_supplicant (sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlo1 -P wpa_md5.pid -c wpa_md5.conf)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=4
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 4 (MD5) selected
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=42:f2:d5:36:72:f0 reason=2
wlo1: Added BSSID 42:f2:d5:36:72:f0 into ignore list, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyEAP" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="MyEAP"
wlo1: BSSID 42:f2:d5:36:72:f0 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlo1: Removed BSSID 42:f2:d5:36:72:f0 from ignore list (clear)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 42:f2:d5:36:72:f0 (SSID='MyEAP' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:f9:fd:8b:f5:8d reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlo1: Added BSSID 5c:f9:fd:8b:f5:8d into ignore list, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyEAP" auth_failures=2 duration=27 reason=CONN_FAILED

Logs from hostapd (sudo hostapd hostapd.conf)
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=4
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=4
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=4
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=4
wlpap: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b
wlpap: STA 0c:dd:24:41:19:9b IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request

Contents of hostapd.conf
##### Hostapd related configuration  ##############################################
interface=wlpap
driver=nl80211
logger_stdout=15
logger_stdout_level=2

##### IEEE 802.11 related configuration #######################################
ssid=MyEAP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
beacon_int=50

##### IEEE 802.1X-2004 related configuration ##################################
ieee8021x=1
eapol_version=2

##### Integrated EAP server ###################################################
eap_server=1
eap_user_file=/home/tbhaxor/eap/eap.user
eap_message=Welcome to MD5 Demo

##### WPA/IEEE 802.11i configuration ##########################################
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
wpa_pairwise=CCMP TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP TKIP

Contents of wpa_md5.conf
network={
        ssid="MyEAP"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        eap=MD5
        identity="user1"        # Match your EAP username
        password="password123"   # Match the corresponding password
}

Contents of eap.user
"user1" MD5 "password123"
"user2" MD5 "anotherpassword"


Does the problem also occur when configured to use WPA-PSK (with everything else being the same)?

I seem to recall EAP-MD5 is not appropriate for WPA because it does not generate the necessary keying material for generating the TKIP or AES-CCMP key hierarchy from. Try PEAP or any of the 802.11i-era EAP methods instead. Some of those legacy EAP types were fine for the early uses of EAP in PPP or original EAPOL (802.1X) on Ethernet, or even "802.1X with WEP" on 802.11 back before WPA. But they were not appropriate even for original WPA (TKIP), and definitely not for modern WPA2 (AES-CCMP) or WPA3.

@grawity_u1686 no luck with psk either. You can check logs and config here

It's something with hostapd I guess, as I am trying to connect with my phone, which reaches to EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED and then just AP-STA-DISCONNECTED. On phone it says "Failed to obtain IP address".
